# nodeIntegration true ignored?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to use a require directive in my js file attached to an html file. However, I am getting a require not defined error message with that file. My understanding is in newer versions of Electron after 5.0 that nodeIntegration was disabled by default. However, even after enabling nodeIntegration in web preferences I still am getting the require error message. My understanding was this nodeIntegration should solve that issue. Why am I still running into not defined issues with require? Here's the relevant section of the main.js file.

EDIT: I was missing a comma between preload and nodeIntegration, so thanks to the individual who pointed that out! However, I am still experiencing the issue. Still getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Second EDIT: Here's a minimal reproduction of the issue. The require function is undefined even when nodeIntegration is set to override it. In the end I'm just trying to read from a local json file but every instance I can find to do so in a simplistic manner when working with electron uses a require in some way, whether it is requiring fs or requiring the file. If the require statement won't function at all I can't make either work.

main.js:

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  })
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Destiny Guide</title>
   <script src="problem.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    Hello World
    <br>
    <h1><a href = "HelloWorld">helloWorld</a><h1>

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

problem.js:

```js
var dataArc = require("./ZeroHourArc.json");
```

Third, and Last, EDIT: see answer below.

Comment: Are you missing a comma between `preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')` and `nodeIntegration:true`?

Comment: @snwflk I was missing that comma, thanks. However, I'm still having the issue for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a complete yet minimal example that reproduces the issue? Where is the error message shown? Is the BrowserWindow displayed?

Comment: By the way, you can use `require` in preload scripts no matter if `nodeIntegration` is on or off (I've tried this and it works fine). To quote the docs on preload scripts: `This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off`.

Comment: @snwflk I updated it with a minimal version of the code.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not sure how I could preload and read a json file in some way, and keep that loaded across a preload script into my html. That is the reason I'm trying to use require and load the json file from the same js script in the first place instead of using preload.

Comment: Hmm, the code you posted works for me: I can load a JSON file. Can you check if there are errors in the DevTools? You can have them displayed on startup using `mainWindow.toggleDevTools()`.

Comment: Ah I see, so the preload script is actually fine, it's just the `problem.js` file that you load in your html file that's broken. Sorry, I thought you were trying to do the require in the preload script.

Comment: @snwflk The error I'm getting is in DevTools. So the code I pasted worked in your environment? is there somehow something wrong with my environment? I directly pulled it from the electron-quick-start app for boilerplate with a few changes, and I had node set up and working properly before I started on this project. As far as I know Node works fine still on my system. So on your setup it worked as expected?

Comment: @snwflk okay if I had taken a moment to step back I would have realized the problem. My editor had made a duplicate file elsewhere in the system with the same name so every time I thought I was editing this app, I was editing a random file. Thus, my changes to main.js weren't syncing across. I edited the right file with nodeIntegration and now it behaves as expected. Sorry for taking up your time over something so simple!

Answer (score 19):

Just try to add `contextIsolation: false` like this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  icon: './public/logo.png',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false}
});
```

Comment: Are there any *dangers* with having `webpreferences` this way if you are not loading external pages that are downloaded? This offers quite a bit of development conveniences but the docs seem to strongly discourage it in favor of the context bridges via preload

Answer (score 9):

In Electron 12, `contextIsolation` will be enabled by default, so `require()` cannot be used in the renderer process unless `nodeIntegration = true` and `contextIsolation = false`.

For more details see: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506

Comment: is the only security pitfall if renderer downloads code from online sources?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit oblivious. I was editing a random file that had the same name and layout as my main.js but it wasn't in the same place. Editing the correct file in the right place, same name, allowed me to make nodeIntegration work as expected.