# Unable to access __dirname variable in Renderer Process, in an ElectronJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to learn ElectronJS right now from the book "**Electron in Action**" (`https://www.amazon.com/Electron-Action-Steve-Kinney/dp/1617294144/`).

The bit of code I'm having difficulty with is one in which I am, through JS code within `<script>` tags in the HTML file loaded into a Renderer Process window, trying to access the `__dirname` variable (which is normally only available in node but in Electron, is supposed to be available to the Chromium context too).

For anybody interested, it's **Listing 2.8** (page : 28). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bookmarker</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello from Electron</h1>
        <p>
            <button class="alert">Current Directory</button>
        </p>
        
        <script>
            const button = document.querySelector('.alert');

            button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {alert(__dirname);});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the Main process:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let main_window = null;

app.on('ready',
() =>
{
    console.log('Hello from Electron');
    main_window = new BrowserWindow();

    main_window.webContents.loadFile('app/index.html');
}
);
```

But it doesn't work. In the developer console of the Rendering Window, each time I click the button, the error spawns which says that `__dirname` is not defined.

I enclose below a screenshot of the Error Message:
[image: The Error Log]

How do I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in main.js while you create a window set `nodeIntegration` to `true`

```
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  })
```

Comment: I only provided the webPreferences:{nodeIntegration:true} pair in the argument object and it still worked for me. Anyways, thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

This is probably NOT RECOMMENDED for production apps but if you must, then, in addition to

`nodeIntegration:true`

add

`contextIsolation: false`

so that your BrowserWindow constructor looks like this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration:true,
        contextIsolation: false
    }
});
```

See solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718760/11054327)

Read more on Context Isolation [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)

Note, that the way this is done at the moment, is by using [Preload Scripts (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuNnmDwgXCQ).

and then, to learn more about the history of Electron security [see here](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/)